# Wordpress PHP conditional tag isn't working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code below in my `page.php` template but the div isn't showing up on the `woocommerce` pages. Rather, nothing shows up. What is wrong with the code?

```
<?php if ( is_page('woocommerce') ): ?>

  <div id="banner">
    <h2>New shop is open!</h2>
  </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: did you get change to `var_dump(is_page('woocommerce'))` ??

Comment: @Gulshan I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: that means did this condition `if(is_page('woocommerce')):` fullfilled or not

Comment: May be your if statement is not fulfilled, also write else : statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
<?php  
    global $post;

     if( $post->ID == 346) { ?>

          <!-- do your stuff here -->

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Does "global" have to be surrounded by anything? The word "global" shows up in the html.

Comment: To make this clear... to check the post for ID 346 is just an arbitrary example to show a) that you can use the curly-brace-syntax instead of the colon-syntax for if-conditions. Both syntaxes are the same, so I don't know how this could help anyway. And b) to check for the post id instead of post name.

Answer (score 0):

This function `is_page` in wordpress is a function to check if a page exist with `id`, `title`, `slug`, array. You can read more about `is_page()` function [in the wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

With your code, you are checking a page with slug or title = "woocommerce" exists or not. Were do you check if this page exists in your wordpress?

Comment: If it is exists, this function will return true. Probably, your code didn't fulfilled. You try add simple text before if and it appear when you test?

Comment: If it exists find out the id and try to check for the id instead for the slug. Most likely there is a typo in the slug or something like that. You can also use is_page for checking for ID as you can see in the documentation (and don't have to to it like @Bilal Ahmed) with global.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another template, like page-woocommerce.php kicking in before page.php. See: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/.